# Stored Procedure that accepts all table fields and updates those values

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

I'm working through a couple practice questions and I've run across this problem, I keep getting an error when trying to execute the procedure that says

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Procedure'."

Can someone please help?

Write a procedure `UpdateTitle` that accepts all the `Title` table columns and will update the title with those values. Raise error messages for the following: The ISBN does not exist The Category and/or Publisher Codes are not valid.

```
Create PROCEDURE UpdateTitle (@ISBN char(10), @SuggestedPrice smallmoney,@NumberInStock smallint,@PublisherCode int,@CategoryCode int)
AS
BEGIN
IF @ISBN is null or @CategoryCode is null or @PublisherCode is null
BEGIN
 RAISERROR ('ISBN,CategoryCode, or PublisherCode is not valid please enter valid data',16,1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN    
 IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Title WHERE ISBN = @ISBN) = 0
 BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('ISBN does not exist.',16,1)
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    SELECT 'Table Sucessfully Updated.';
    UPDATE Title 
    SET SuggestedPrice = @SuggestedPrice
    WHERE ISBN = @ISBN;

    BEGIN
     IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Title WHERE ISBN = @ISBN) = 0
     BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('ISBN does not exist.',16,1)
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    SELECT 'Table Sucessfully Updated.';
    UPDATE Title 
    SET NumberInStock = @NumberInStock
    WHERE ISBN = @ISBN;
  END

          BEGIN
     IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Title WHERE ISBN = @ISBN) = 0
     BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('ISBN does not exist.',16,1)
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    SELECT 'Table Sucessfully Updated.';
    UPDATE Title 
    SET PublisherCode = @PublisherCode
    WHERE ISBN = @ISBN;
  END
          BEGIN
     IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Title WHERE ISBN = @ISBN) = 0
     BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('ISBN does not exist.',16,1)
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    SELECT 'Table Sucessfully Updated.';
    UPDATE Title 
    SET CategoryCode = @CategoryCode
    WHERE ISBN = @ISBN;
  END

 END
END
END
END
END
END
GO
```

Then

```
 Execute Procedure UpdateTitle @ISBN ='1021031040', @suggestedproce ='40' , @NumberInStock ='10', @PublisherCode = '200', @CategoryCode = '1'
```

Comment: What does "are not valid" mean? Are there lookup tables somewhere with category and publisher codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Execute Procedure UpdateTitle ...
```

Should be:

```
EXEC dbo.UpdateTitle ...
```

Some other comments:

- ISBN is no longer limited to 10 characters ([this change happened in 2007, if you believe WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)).
- [Always use the schema prefix when creating or referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).
- You only need to check that the ISBN is valid once. And you shouldn't do so using a count IMHO, especially since - presumably - that is the key and it could only ever return 0 or 1 anyway.
- You shouldn't select "update successful" and then perform the update. You should make sure the update was successful before telling the user it was successful.
- There is no reason to separate this out into multiple updates either.
- Please be liberal with carriage returns, indenting and whitespace. The value in readability is worth the extra cost in typing it (since you only type it once, but you will read it multiple times).
- Use `RETURN;` as an exit mechanism so that you don't have to nest `IF` and `ELSE` multiple times.
- Always use `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of your procedures.
- You probably want to customize the message to tell the user which parameter(s) were invalid.
- Oh yeah, and [please future-proof your code by using semi-colons to terminate statements](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

Here is a much more concise version that satisfies all of your requirements:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateTitle
  @ISBN           CHAR(10), 
  @SuggestedPrice SMALLMONEY,
  @NumberInStock  SMALLINT,
  @PublisherCode  INT,
  @CategoryCode   INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(255);

  IF @ISBN IS NULL OR @CategoryCode IS NULL OR @PublisherCode IS NULL
  BEGIN
    SELECT @msg = 'The following parameter(s) were invalid:'
      + CASE WHEN @ISBN IS NULL THEN ' @ISBN' ELSE '' END 
      + CASE WHEN @CategoryCode IS NULL THEN ' @CategoryCode' ELSE '' END 
      + CASE WHEN @PublisherCode IS NULL THEN ' @PublisherCode' ELSE '' END;

    RAISERROR (@msg, 11, 1);
    RETURN;
  END

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Title WHERE ISBN = @ISBN)
  BEGIN
    SET @msg = 'ISBN %s does not exist.';
    RAISERROR(@msg, 11, 1, @ISBN);
    RETURN;
  END

  BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE dbo.Title
      SET SuggestedPrice = @SuggestedPrice,
          NumberInStock  = @NumberInStock,
          PublisherCode  = @PublisherCode,
          CategoryCode   = @CategoryCode
      WHERE ISBN = @ISBN;

    SELECT 'Update successful.';
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    SET @msg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR(@msg, 11, 1);
  END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the help could you explain why it would be EXEC dbo.UpdateTitle instead of Execute Procedure UpdateTitle?

Comment: Because you don't have to tell SQL Server that you are executing a stored procedure. If you ever have doubts about Transact-SQL syntax, don't guess, check the documentation. [The syntax is rather thoroughly documented precisely so that you don't have to guess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).